# return child function addEventListener value as async parent function return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have one asynchronous call, inside one addEventListener function, I need to pass addEventListener output as output of parent asynchronous call

parent async call has to wait until  addEventListener function return value.

```
async abc () {
    let result;
    await someObj.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        let childres;
        some_function(someVar)
    }
    e.data = result; )
    return result;
}
```

Comment: x.addEventListener is not async (so don't `await` it), it just assigns a function to act as some kind of event handler.  Do you want what happens when you click to be async?  `x.addEventListener("click", async function (e) { ... });`

Comment: @james its not working async I added,  can you help me with working block of code or any reference

Comment: I can't help because I have no idea what you expect to happen to `result` when that button gets clicked.  You can't "return result" because returning a value from a click handler does nothing.

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that are less frequently downvoted and closed.

Comment: async abc () {let result; someObj.addEventListener("click",async  function(e){ let _result; childres; some_function(someVar)} e.obj ="test";  e.obj =_result; return _result;  )return result;}

Comment: @AJT82 please don’t add comments along the lines of “use X, it’s so much easier than Y”. We had enough problems with people adding “use jQuery” to every question…

Comment: @James I am getting e.data as some values, and I need to return child function values to parent, here child function is listener

Comment: @Nagavalli [edit] your question, don’t comment with new code. While you’re in there, add some text describing the issue, what you expect to happen that doesn’t, what happens that you don’t expect to happen, etc. again, [ask] lists a lot of what we want to see in a question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, not saying it is easier at all. Probably the contrary. Angular pushes reactive programming somewhat more than promises, so I don't see why I cannot even **mention** it?

Comment: I have one asynchronous call, inside one addEventListener function, I need to pass addEventListener output as output of parent asynchronous call

parent async call has to wait until addEventListener function return value.

Comment: You have to provide more context. An event listener is usually a function that gets called multiple times, but you can only return from a function once. So how exactly is the "parent function" supposed to interact with the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to return something from `addEventListener`. You can't do that, because any `return`s will be called within the listener, not the main function. You can, however, *resolve a promise* within the event listener, and wait for the promise to be resolved to continue execution. Here's a simple async-addEventListener implementation I set up as an example:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("my-btn");

function asyncAddEventListener(
  element,
  type,
  listener,
  options = {
    once: true,
  }
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const callback = (event) => listener(event, resolve, reject);
    element.addEventListener(type, callback, options);
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log("main start");
  
  // event listener only triggers once
  const data = await asyncAddEventListener(
    btn,
    "click",
    ({ currentTarget }, resolve) => {
      resolve(currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value"));
    }
  );
  console.log(data);
  
  console.log("main end");
}

main();
```

```html
<button id="my-btn" data-value="secret data">Click me!</button>
```